# Static List of Objects out Class in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

[Static List of all Objects of Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592278/static-list-of-all-objects-of-class)
Is this working with Kotlin if yes can you provide an example?

Right now my interface does not have the List and i am creating a companion Object in both implementations. But it feels wrong somehow.... Pls help me to figure this out :)

I have four ways right now to do this i will show two here because the fourth one would require a more complex **UML**. Mybe this is actually how you do it if not maybe one of you has an idea ;)

My Code in Kotlin approach one:

```
interface IMyClass {
}

class MyClassOne : IMyClass {
     companion object {
        var myClassList: ArrayList<IMyClass> = ArrayList()
    }
    constructor() {
        println(myClassList)
    }
}

class MyClassTwo : IMyClass {
     companion object {
        var myClassList: ArrayList<IMyClass> = ArrayList()
    }
    constructor() {
        println(myClassList)
    }
}
```

My Code in Kotlin approach two:

```
interface IMyClass {
    companion object {
       var myClassList: ArrayList<IMyClass> = ArrayList()
    }
}

class MyClassOne : IMyClass {
    constructor() {
        println(IMyClass.myClassList)
    }
}

class MyClassTwo : IMyClass {
    constructor() {
        println(IMyClass.myClassList)
    }
}
```

My Code in Kotlin approach three:

```
interface IMyClass {
    var myClassList: ArrayList<IMyClass>
}

class MyClassOne {
    companion object : IMyClass{
        override var myList: ArrayList<IMyClass>
            get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
            set(value) {}
    }
}

class MyClassTwo {
companion object : IMyClass{
        override var myList: ArrayList<IMyClass>
            get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
            set(value) {}
    }
}
```

My Code in Java:

```
public interface IMyClass {
 List<IMyClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class MyClassOne implements IMyClass {
    public MyClassOne() {
        System.out.println(myClassList );
    }
}

public class MyClassTwo implements IMyClass {
    public MyClassTwo() {
        System.out.println(myClassList);
    }
}
```

Comment: "in Java this is easy for me xD" ... then why do you fail to do the same in Kotlin? Kotlin isn't that much different to not be able to transform your Java solution into Kotlin.

Comment: i can i have some ways to do it but i am not happy with them ;) @Tom

Comment: as long as you don't enforce a rule that you must have at least one item in the list lol :-)

Comment: The kotlin equivalent of the java code you posted would actually be your second approach. however, if you require that each implementation of your interface to handle the initialization of the list then your third approach would be the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i decided to go for my third option:

```
interface IMyClass {
    var myClassList: ArrayList<IMyClass>
}

class MyClassOne {
    companion object : IMyClass{
        override var myList: ArrayList<IMyClass>
            get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
            set(value) {}
    }
}

class MyClassTwo {
companion object : IMyClass{
        override var myList: ArrayList<IMyClass>
            get() = TODO("not implemented") //To change initializer of created properties use File | Settings | File Templates.
            set(value) {}
    }
}
```