# Static List of all Objects of Class

Tags: uml

I wanted to implement a **static** **List** for my **Class** which contains all **Objects** of the **Class** like in the following **UML** approach.

[image]

Is this the right way to write the UML?

There is also a question which uses this UML if you know Kotlin i would be happy if you can help me there too ;) [Static List of Objects out Class in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577698/static-list-of-objects-out-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost correct. Instead of `List<IMyClass>` the regular UML notation is `IMyClass[*]`.

The UML 2.5.1 specification, section 9.5.4 gives the following notation syntax for a property:

`<property> ::= [<visibility>] [‘/’] <name> [‘:’ <prop-type>] [‘[‘ <multiplicity-range> ‘]’] [‘=’ <default>] [‘{‘<prop-modifier > [‘,’ <prop-modifier >]* ’}’]`

In your case, the prop-type is `IMyClass` and the multiplicity-range is `*`.

Comment: Cool and what about the https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class.html#class-template should i use it or not? And should i add a arrow from the interface to itself because it is using itself?

Comment: Answer to first question: You stated your goal as "I wanted to implement a static List for my Class which contains all Objects of the Class". I think in a UML design, you shouldn't bother whether it's a List, Set, Array or whatever. But if you do want to expose this detail, then you would have to define these collection classes as templated classes. Answer to second question: You must choose: _either_ use a property inside the class rectangle _or_ draw an arrow as in Bruno's answer. These notations are equivalent.

Comment: Not using that, but couldn't `List<IMyClass>` be also interpreted as the latter UML def: _<prop-constraint> is an expression that specifies a constraint that applies to the Property._ (a bad definition like quite some in that document). So the "constraint" is the generic type. UML has definition for generics, but how would you denote a use?

Comment: I don't know how to denote a use. I hope some other UML expert reads this and knows the answer. What you could do is first define a class template called ``List``, then define a class called ``ListOfIMyClass`` using that template and then define the property as ``myClassList : ListOfIMyClass``. But I wouldn't do that, because ``ListOfIMyClass`` is not implemented in Kotlin.

Comment: Sincerely to not warn the OP about the use of the visibility _public_ deserves a DV ... (but I don't, I am probably too gentle ^^)

Comment: @bruno, ``IMyClass`` is an interface. The UML spec says: "An Interface is a kind of Classifier that represents a declaration of a set of public Features (...)". Interfaces don't have private members, because an interface should only specify the external behavior that all classes implementing the interface have in common. Which private members these classes use to do that, is up to those classes and should not be prescribed by the interface.

Comment: I think there is one thing missing @www.admiraalit.nl I think the IMyClass needs to use Itself right?

Comment: Do you mean that there is a ≪use≫-dependency missing from IMyClass to itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use the stereotype to specify you use a list, for instance :

[image]

or if you prefer :

[image]

Note : are you sure you want it *public* ? this is dangerous

---

Edit for the remark of @qwerty_so: *it does not make sense to stereotype an association with `<<list>>` where you place a multiplicity which makes it a "list" already. Looks like an over-definition too me*

The multiplicity indicates a *collection*, and there are four types of collection depending on *isOrdered* and *isUnique* properties (c.f. [formal-17-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) §7.5.3.2 Multiplicities, Table 7.1 Collection types for MultiplicityElements, page 34) :

> ```
> isOrdered  | isUnique | Collection Type
> -----------+----------+-----------------
>    false   |   true   |      Set
>     true   |   true   |   OrderedSet
>    false   |  false   |      Bag
>     true   |  false   |    Sequence
> ```

Furthermore a *list* is one of the subtypes of *Sequence*, so the multiplicity "*" is far from indicating a "list" already.

Comment: but why the <<list>> i think thats wrong if you use it in the variable section hmm .... @bruno

Comment: @Mosch the stereotype is not wrong at all, why do you think that ?

Comment: (1) This stereotype is not defined in UML, so you would have to define it first. UML has a special notation for defining stereotypes. (2) The name of the property (``myClassList`` in this case) must be notated near the arrowhead, not in the middle of the arrow.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I can move the labels where I want in the diagram, fortunately, so I use the more practical place

Comment: @bruno i was thinking IMyClass[*] should be sufficient but maybe i am wrong

Comment: @Mosch there are plenty ways to support a sequence, if you do not say how through a stereotype how to know what you decided ? I am surprized the other answer do not say you how to indicate that choice ;-)

Comment: It depends. I think it's too much detail for a UML diagram to specify whether it's a ``List`` or a different type of collection.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl are you saying UML is wrong to have stereotype and to allow to show them on the diagrams ? This is not my way to think ^^

Comment: I agree with @www.admiraalit.nl stereotypes should be used for **meta** types, not for model types. Otherwise we could also have stereotypes for «date», «HasTable», etc...

Comment: @GeertBellekens you confuse _how_ to define a stereotype and _where_ they can be used, I strongly encourage you to reread the norm about the profile/stereotype ...

Comment: @bruno No I don't. You are using a stereotype with the name «list». But a list is a (model) type just like *HashTable*, or *Set*, or any other type. We generally don't use stereotypes to specify the *type*, but only to specify the *metatype*.

Comment: @GeertBellekens,  In this case, the stereotype is used to specify how the multiplicity ``*`` is implemented, namely using a Kotlin ``List``. So it's more an implementation detail rather than a model type. If it is important to convey this implementation detail in UML, then this stereotype might be a good idea. But again, I wouldn't expect this amount of detail in a UML diagram.

Comment: @GeertBellekens the first standard stereotype is _Auxilary_, and it is not a type, so why do you imagine I directly specify the type using _list_ ? I again strongly encourage you to refresh your knowledge about the profile/stereotype

Comment: I also think it does not make sense to stereotype an association with `<<list>>` where you place a multiplicity which makes it a "list" already. Looks like an over-definition too me. (Btw.: Geert is an UML-pro; just that his UML practice is a bit EA-bent, like mine...)

Comment: @qwerty_so pity do not say the multiplicity "*" implies a _list_, I edited my answer about that (not practical to give details in a remark). Out of that, Geert is an UML-pro, very fine, am I a novice ? You know, even I am the _author_ of an UML tool that does not protect me at all from mistakes, do you think to be the _user_ of UML tool(s) even 'expert' allows to always be right ? ;-)

Comment: Not saying that you are a noob. It just sounded like you put Geert in that drawer ;-) And now: what is a `list` and how does it differentiate compared to `Sequence` and `collection`? Where are those terms defined?